# Teradata DB connection issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, teradata

I've installed Teradata image(https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B06Y4Z54R5) on AWS account. I'm able to log in and connect to DB. To save costs, I've stopped the instance and restarted it and try to connect to the DB again. I'm getting the following error.

```
SMP001-01:~ # bteq

 Teradata BTEQ 16.20.00.07 (32-bit) for LINUX. PID: 12571
 Copyright 1984-2018 Teradata. All rights reserved.
 Enter your logon or BTEQ command:
.logon DBC

.logon DBC
Password: 

 *** Warning: RDBMS CRASHED OR SESSIONS RESET.  RECOVERY IN PROGRESS.
^C^C^C *** Warning: Exiting because of three BREAKs!

 *** Exiting BTEQ.
```

I've tried restarting the DB using the following commands but it is not working.

```
/etc/init.d/tpa start

SMP001-01:~ # pdestate -a             
PDE state is RUN/READY.
DBS state is 0/-1: DBS is not running
SMP001-01:~ # psh pdestate -a

<---------------------  localhost  -------------------------------->
PDE state is RUN/READY.
DBS state is 0/-1: DBS is not running
```

Comment: Did you successfully stop the database before stopping the instance, as documented in the Getting Started guide? You could try an explicit stop/restart with `tpareset -x Attempt cleanup` and waiting for pdestate DOWN/HARDSTOP followed by `tpareset -f`. Use the `status` command in the vprocmanager utility to verify the AMPs are all ONLINE.

Comment: @Fred can you please share the link of this getting started guide? i've stopped the DB sucessfully and have checked status after. status was down/hardstop.

But when i stopped the instance/restarted it and tried to connect that is when the issue is happening

Comment: Currently version is called [DIY on AWS Install & Admin Guide](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/4WrLDvBuDeEmmauVOmUMKQ/jSQDAKxUvD17Oyh4YaC77w). So after `tpareset -f`  the state is still RUN/READY?

Comment: teradata PDE state is RUN/READY. but says DBS state is 0/-1: DBS is not running. I've tried starting and forced restart the DB but still this state remains @Fred

Comment: What is the output from `/etc/init.d/tpa start`? Run `vprocmanager` and use `status notonline` to display any problems.

Comment: @Fred i used a free developer tier image, it says 
Teradata devleopers edition uses SSD local storage.  Local storeage is lost on stopping it.  

Local storage is temporary or ephemeral and is ideal for testing and development where you do not need to keepdata. Local storage uses SSD or HDD media.


http://www.nazmulhuda.info/teradata-database-instance-with-local-storage-on-aws-not-working-after-shutdown-the-instance


https://support.teradata.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=0dd9c7ab1b97fb00682ca8233a4bcb06&view_source=searchResult


Could this be the reason??

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. If you have local storage then stopping the instance makes the Teradata filesystem and all the database contents go away, including the dictionary tables. You can force reinitialization as documented in that first article, or delete the instance and spin up a new one.